# Understading pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C. I'm having difficulty in understanding the difference between the following two

```
int N = 16
double (*XX)[2] = malloc(2*N*sizeof(double));
```

and

```
int N = 16
double *XX[2] = malloc(2*N*sizeof(double));
```

If I write the first one it is getting compiled. However, the second one is giving following error. Please explain

```
error: invalid initializer
```

Edit: I also wanted to ask what the malloc is doing in above correct case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`double (*XX)[2]` is a pointer to an array with two `double` elements.

`double *XX[2]` is a pointer to an array with two `double *` elements.

`malloc` is for **dynamic memory allocation**, for example:

```c
char array_stack[2]; // 2 chars allocated on the stack (no need for free())
char *array_heap = malloc(2 * sizeof(char)); // 2 chars allocated on the heap
// later...
free(array_heap); // heap memory must be freed by user
```

FYI:

```c
char array_stack[2]; // this is nevertheless a pointer
char *array = array_stack; // this works, because array_stack is a pointer to a char
```

For more information about the stack and heap: [Stack vs Heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)

```c
double *XX[2] = malloc(2*N*sizeof(double));
```

Does not work because it expects two elements as initializer. For example:

```c
double _1, _2;
double *XX[2] = {&_1, &_2};
```

If you want do to this with malloc you need to change it to a pointer to an array with double pointers like this:

```c
double **XX = malloc(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case

```
 double (*XX)[2]
```

XX is a pointer to array of 2 doubles

In this case

```
 double *XX[2]
```

XX is array of 2 pointers to double

EDIT:
Others have explained malloc, but in laymans terms: With malloc you reserve a amount of memory on your computer using malloc, and then store values in the memory you have reserved with malloc

Comment: Can you also please add answer on what 'malloc' is doing in my question

Answer (score 0):

1. `malloc` would return a pointer to some memory location (`void*`).
2. `double (*XX)[2]` is **a pointer to an array of doubles** - no problem: compiler knows how to cast from `void*` to `double*`.
3. `double *XX[2]` is **an array of double pointers** (I prefer write it this way `double* XX[2]` it is easier, for me, understand that we are talking about *double pointer(s)*) - compiler does not know conversion from `void*` to *array of double pointers*.

Answer (score 0):

XX in the first case is just a pointer which point to an array with two double elements. So "sizeof(XX)" is just 4.

Second case:
XX is a array name with two element whose type is (double*).
So the following code will be OK.
    double *XX[2];
    XX[1]= malloc(20*sizeof(double));

Answer (score 0):

The 1st definition `double (*XX)[2]` defines a single value, a pointer here. A single variable can be initialised by a single value, as returned by `= malloc(...)`.

The 2nd (`double *XX[2]`) defines an array. Array initialisers look like this `= {<init value(s)>}`.